# Javascript: || operator for variable assignment

Tags: javascript

I have two small examples code:

```
// example 1:
var x;
...
x = x || 'some value'; //assign some value to x if x has no value
...

// example 2:
var y;
...
y || (y = 'some value'); //assign some value to y if y has no value
...
```

My question is:
1. Will x be reassign it's value in example 1 when x already has value?
2. Is example 2 better then example 1?

(My english isn't good. Thanks for your reading and answering :D)

Comment: 1) Depends on the value. 2) Better in which sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes. If `x` has a truthy value, it will be assigned back to itself. If it doesn't, the default `'some value'` will be assigned to it.
2. There may be a tiny performance benefit in example 2, but example 1 is the standard idiom. Consistency with other programmers is useful because they'll understand your code more easily. Unless you're doing lots of default value initialization in a large loop, the performance gain should be negligible.

Comment: thanks @Barmar, your answer is very clear and complete

Comment: My guess would be that `if (!y) y = 'some value';` is just as common (and definitely better / more widespread than example 2).

Answer (score 1):

`x` will just reassign it's value since it has already a value

```
    var x = 'foo';
    x = x || 'some value';
  //  result: x = 'foo' //reassigned the value of x
```

- In terms of readability, i would prefer the `example1`

Comment: The assignment `x = x` will still take place, so yes, `x` gets assigned the value it already has.

Comment: I got it now @Felix,  kinda little bit confused a while ago.. :)

Answer (score -1):

in example 1, javascript assigns at first pass value undefined to x.
at second pass (when your code is running)
x comes with value undefined at line

var x;

then || operator acts as following. Consider having :

left || right

if(left is not undefined (globally resolved to true) then return left
else return right

so yes a value will be reassigned to x (either x itself or 1)
As x resolved to undefined, or operator resolves right, and then assigns 1 to x.
so x = x||1, ends in x's value === 1

second example
no it adds uncomplicated logic (but still works)

Comment: `||` does not have a lot to do with `undefined`. And how does it matter that `undefined` is a global identifier?

Comment: || does have to do with undefined as undefined resolves to false for a boolean conversion. And || does check the boolean value of its operand. So in ( undefined || soomethingelse), the expression soomethingelse will be executed
And I didn't mean undefined to be a global identifier. Globally refers to the left operand to be true (e.g false, null, 0..) so the right operand is not executed.